# custom update table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
code item   price   start date   end date 
--------------------------------------------------
art1         2.47    01/01/2015   31/03/2015
art1         1.23    01/04/2015   21/09/2015 
art1         3.55    22/09/2015   01/01/2018
```

When I will add a new line which start date exists already between a start date and end date in the table .

1. I need to update the end date in the table with the `start date -1` of the new line to be added
2. add the new line .

For example, I have a new line to added:

```
code item   price   start date   end date 
-----------------------------------------
art1         4      28/12/2015   31/05/2018
```

What I expect as a final result is the following table :

```
code item   price   start date   end date 
--------------------------------------------------
art1         2.47    01/01/2015   31/03/2015
art1         1.23    01/04/2015   21/09/2015 
art1         3.55    22/09/2015   27/12/2015 
art1           4      28/12/2015  31/05/2018
```

Comment: please post your attempt too

Comment: What should happen when the new date is between two start dates and end dates

Comment: Will the new row always follow the last current row? Should it be rejected if not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in T-SQL, make the start date and end dates of your new item a parameter, so that you can modify the end date of the one already in the table as per your requirement.

You can check if the previous item's end date falls between your new item's start and end dates by using sysdate with your new start and end dates.